# Is it possible to use a StackRegressor on pretrained models?

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn

I want to use scikit-learn's StackedRegressor to build an ensemble but I want to use pretrained keras models. Basically I want to utilize the meta-regressor to use each of the base models in the best way possible but I don't need them to be trained. Something like

```
regressor_1 = KerasRegressor(build_fn)
regressor_2 = KerasRegressor(build_fn)
regressor_3 = KerasRegressor(build_fn)
regressors = [('r1', regressor_1),
              ('r2', regressor_2),
              ('r3', regressor_3)]

xgboost = XGBRegressor(learning_rate=0.01, n_estimators=3460,
                       max_depth=3, min_child_weight=0,
                       gamma=0, subsample=0.7,
                       colsample_bytree=0.7,
                       objective='reg:linear', nthread=-1,
                       scale_pos_weight=1, seed=27,
                       reg_alpha=0.00006)
stack_gen = StackingRegressor(estimators=regressors,
                                final_estimator=xgboost,
                                n_jobs=-1)
```

But again without fitting fitting base models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need the `stackingRegressor` for this.

do something like this:

```
prediction =[]
for reg in regressors:
     predictions.append(reg.predict(X))

xgboost.fit_predict(prediction)
```

Answer (score 0):

BY description and definition the sklearn's StackingRegressor module uses the predictions of the multiple regressors to infuse them into another regression model

> "the predictions of each individual estimator are stacked together and
> used as input to a final estimator to compute the prediction. "

So it inevitably needs to fit (produce the algorithm) to some data in order to receive the (simply described) if-then or y=ax+bz logic and put the ifs and x-z into the equation.

I'm thinking, in your scenario you might just need an ensemble technique, that is take the "best" (least error) or simply the average of the predictions.
More on the topic and the sklearn modules for the purpose:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html